# npm installs wrong package version

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I'm trying to install `karma` using the following command `npm i karma@^1.0.0`. `npm` installs `karma@1.0.0` rather than latest version `karma@1.6.0`. After a little investigation, I figured out that these commands work: `npm i karma@^1` and `npm i karma@^"1.0.0"` (enclose command with double quotes). Anyone can explain how it should work?

I guess that this is not related to karma since it's reproducible with any package.

npm - 4.0.5, node - 7.4.0

Thanks.

Comment: What version of NPM are you using? (`npm -v`)

Comment: npm - 4.0.5, node - 7.4.0

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> Note that most version ranges must be put in quotes so that your shell
>   will treat it as a single argument.

And the example given there follows the advice:

```
npm install sax@">=0.1.0 <0.2.0"
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it.